# Flume : Kafka sink not able to get all tweets

Tags: twitter, apache-kafka, flume

I'm trying to collect tweets from Twitter API, and write them to Kafka via Flume. I use a Kafka sink. The problem is that the Kafka Sink does not collect all the tweets collected by Flume. I ran zookeeper and kafka server, created topic twitter and listenned to the topic with a consumer. for instance, for 1000 tweets that Flume collects, Kafka only displays 100, after 1 minute processing.
Here is flume conf file :

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels= MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = kafka


TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type =   org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel


TwitterAgent.sinks.kafka.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10020
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1300


TwitterAgent.sinks.kafka.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafka.topic = twitter
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafka.brokerList = localhost:9092
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafka.batchsize = 100
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafka.request.required.acks = -1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked the logs? You might find some hints there..

Comment: Rather than using Memory channel can you try file channel(keep capacity little large) and validate how many tweets you have in channel.